# Check if array of strings matching all interface properties

Tags: arrays, typescript, webpack, interface

I have an array of strings that has to match an interface properties names

```
export interface MyType1 {
  propName1: number;
  propName2: string;
  propNameX: number;
}

tableColumns: string[] = [
  'propName1',
  'propName2',
  'propNameX'
];
```

Initially I was thinking to convert an interface to an array of strings but haven't found a solution that works.

So now I am wondering if there anyway to see if array of strings matching an interface or something like that.

I've tried using https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys but it won't work in my case as I have no access to webpack configuration, otherwise throwing compiled error in the browser.

Need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply

```
const tableColumns: (keyof MyType1)[] = [
  'propName1',
  'propName2',
  'propNameX'
];
```

Comment: any thoughts on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75905446/creating-an-array-based-on-interface ?

Answer (score 0):

String literals

```
type MyType1 = [
  'propName1',
  'propName2',
  'propNameX',
]

const tableColumns: MyType1 = [
  'propName1',
  'propName2',
  'propNameX'
];
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq4IEYoF4oG0CwAoKUA5GAE4D2YAcgIYC2KhANHgceVXRAExMtGkUa9ABq9cAXTx4AxmQB2AZ2BRg1AEYAbCAGEyGgK61FALlgIkqDDnz92QhsxttBnHo9YCOIwnnEBuIA)