# How to type a const

Tags: typescript, types

This is a followup of this [queston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75905375/check-if-array-of-strings-matching-all-interface-properties)

I have this code

```
export const tableColumns = [
  'propName1',
  'propName2',
  'propNameX'
] as const;

export type tableColumns = (typeof tableColumns)[number];
```

I have this interface that I want to type my `tableColumns` columns with:

```
export interface MyType1 {
  propName1: number;
  propName2: string;
  propNameX: number;
}

export const tableColumns: (keyof MyType1)[] = [
  'propName1',
  'propName2',
  'propNameX'
] as const;

export type tableColumns = (typeof tableColumns)[number];
```

got an error `cannot be assigned to the mutable type '(keyof MyType1)[]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an array is a mutable type and you are applying a [`const`
assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to `tableColumns`, use the utility type [`Readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#readonlytype) for typing `tableColumns` (e.g. `push` is not allowed anymore):

```
export const tableColumns: Readonly<(keyof MyType1)[]> = [
  'propName1',
  'propName2',
  'propNameX'
] as const;
```

A `const` assertion is doing the following:

> [...] array literals become readonly tuples

**Edit:**

You can also use `readonly` to make `tableColumns` immutable:

```
export const tableColumns: readonly (keyof MyType1)[] = [...] as const;
```

Comment: I've just did that `readonly (keyof MyType1)[]` that was solved the problem but I wonder if it is doing the same as `Readonly<(keyof MyType1)[]>` ?

Comment: Oh, of course, you are right. `readonly` makes `tableColumns` immutable and therefore is also good to go. I have added this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive all of your data and types from an initial array of entries and a type map of strings to types that you'd like to use. Here's an example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOAVcECyBDMUC8UDeAUFFAM4ICWAdgOYBcpFNA3EVJQK4C2ARhPPRx58WAXxYEAxgHtKZKMHTcANhADCUpV0oBRShQgkcUANqtjAIjDwpYAHLpOEAIzmANFHODe8cwF1XZpbWdg4QAExuHmTwVNR+AcQWVjb2jgAakZ5c3vEEvlDohtKywKTowOQkAGbkBlDwEOgAJjJKIFAAFA3Nre3G0bHuANYQIFJVsAjIkBhgvgCUxr7ioJBQAEoQ0vBNAGLWnLr6JACqlOQyADyIUBAAHsAQlE2G3S2UbSYDNMOj45NIFCzXwAPiMhESR3g7SoUBuhSgUJAxgADL5fPQ4ICZphjEjjE50aJxMU5AplGoNFoSPQ3r15Ch-uSVOpNJwdHoYgZjF4+L5Ufz8rhmZS2RzjgA6TiYDodYxDBY4MFDeYsYjEAD0GoAegB+AgEVbQRCKFlU9lGI1M02irRQ2okHnZPkCtWanX6w0oKCoEDTZxGTbbPYHe0GM4XSiXK0TEWsu2ch1OoTwUFuqBavUEIA)

```ts
type StrTypeMap = {
  string: string;
  number: number;
};

const tableColumnEntries = [
  ["propName1", "number"],
  ["propName2", "string"],
  ["propNameX", "number"],
] as const satisfies readonly (readonly [string, keyof StrTypeMap])[];

type RecordFromEntriesUnion<T extends readonly [string, keyof StrTypeMap]> = {
  [Entry in T as Entry[0]]: StrTypeMap[Entry[1]];
};

const tableColumns: readonly typeof tableColumnEntries[number][0][] = tableColumnEntries.map(([k]) => k);
    //^? const tableColumns: readonly ("propName1" | "propName2" | "propNameX")[]

type TableColumn = typeof tableColumnEntries[number][0];
   //^? type TableColumn = "propName1" | "propName2" | "propNameX"

type MyType1 = RecordFromEntriesUnion<typeof tableColumnEntries[number]>;
   //^? type MyType1 = { propName1: number; propName2: string; propNameX: number; }
```